# Array from Checkbox Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

Through [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-example) that I found on the Internet, I want to store in an array the selected elements of a Selection list in Angular material

```
         <mat-selection-list #shoes>
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" [(selected)]="shoe.checked">
          {{shoe.title}}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>

      <p>
        Options : {{ shoes.selectedOptions.selected }}
      </p>

      <pre>
        Options selected: {{this.result | json}}
      </pre>
```

But, I can't fill the array with the selections I make manually. [I leave the link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-option-checked) of the project.

```
export class ListSelectionExample implements OnInit {
  typesOfShoes: any[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.typesOfShoes = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Aaa',
        checked: true,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Bbb',
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Ccc',
        checked: true,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Ddd',
        checked: false,
      },
    ];
  }

  get result() {
    return this.typesOfShoes.filter(shoe => shoe.checked);
  }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOEPB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a just a couple of things:

- the `mat-selection-list` needs to be binded with some property on the component where it will reflects the changes. You can do this by adding a new variable in the component to hold the ids of the selected items and add `[(ngModel)]="<your_new_variable>"` to the `mat-selection-list` in your template. (remember to define your variable in the .ts file)
- you need to tell the `mat-list-option` which selected/deselected property of the items it will track in the variable created above (in this case the id of the shoe is perfect).

I updated your example with those 2 additions [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-option-checked-afwbqw)

Comment: Thank, What is the option to see only the shoe.title Values: `{{shoes.selectedOptions.selected}}`